# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Notification replaced by new notification in notification bar

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am able to implement Push Notificatios in my Worklight project with the Android environment; it all works well and notifications are received, however my issue is that when a notification is received in the device, then it removes the previous notification from notification bar - replaces it.

Android device used: 2.3, 3.0. 4.0, 4.1 (same issue in all).

Worklight: v6.0.0.20130614

Comment: Can you please paste your code.

Comment: You mean to say that you receive one notification and that notification is replaced by new notification?

Comment: A quick tip: use different ID for each notification.

Comment: i have the issue in Worklight for andorid device, i know how to handle it in core Android Platform.

Comment: @sram, what is the exact Worklight version? Look at the About window in Eclipse and provide the build version.

Comment: @idan Worklight v: 6.0.0.20130614..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Worklight, this is by design - each notification received uses the same notification ID, thus replacing the existing one in the notification bar. Which explains why you only see 1 notification at a time.

The code that handles this is packaged within the Worklight Android .jar file provided in the project and cannot be altered.

If you are an IBM customer, I suggest you to get in touch with your IBM contact person.

Comment: thanks, means we are not able to alter the notification Id which is same for all?

Comment: AFAIK, that is correct - you cannot. As said, for inquiries or possible changes contact IBM (if you are a business partner or customer, you should know how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [updating](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating) your notification with the same id, create a new one with a unique id.